# SSIS: How to generate a date value into the data flow?

Tags: ssis

I'm using SSIS to convert data from SQLAnywhere to SQL Server with mostly the same schema in both databases. But I've introduced a new column `CreatedAt datetimeoffset not null` for which I need to generate a value into the SSIS data flow.

I was looking for a *Source Component* to generate custom values, but found only the *Script Component* that can be configured to be used as source. Is there an easier way to generate a value into the data flow?

Answer (score 3):

The *Derived Column Component* can be used to generate values into the data flow. Put it somewhere between your source and destination and configure it to have a *Derived Column Name* **CreatedAt**, select *add as new column* for *Derived Column* and specify `GetDate()` as *Expression*. It will automatically suggest **DT_DBTIMESTAMP** as *Data Type*.
[image]